# how to omit white space in web parts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, branding, multilingual

hi I used webparts like announcement and news and promoted links in my page but we have white space in left site of them what should we do ?
[image]

Comment: I guess it's related to the column of the webpart zone, not the webpart itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current page in **SharePoint Designer 2013** open & edit it in `Advanced Mode`  look after the correct **column** and modify the width of it.

[image]